# Terminal command to find out if a server is virtual or physical

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine

I am looking for a terminal command which doesn't require the executing user to be in the sudoers group and also to be universal and not requiring to install additional packages. So far I have found that if the system has systemd installed then I can use:

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: mint
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
           Boot ID: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  Operating System: Linux Mint LMDE
            Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-6-amd64
```

and under Icon name and Chassis I can see if it is VM or physical machine. But I was wondering if I can use `lscpu`, especially since it is more universal method than `hostnamectl` and it doesn't require systemd. My theory is that if the CPU has only one thread per core and also not listed minimum and maximum CPU frequency this should be an indication that the server is indeed virtualized.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2500.488
CPU max MHz:           3500.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4988.18
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

I know that the if a CPU has only one thread per core doesn't necessarily means that it is VM for sure, but then all modern CPUs should have 2 threads per core and in addition I can also take into account the lack/presence of minimum and maximum CPU frequency in the `lscpu` output.

Comment: _"all modern CPUs should have 2 threads per core"_ - Where do you get that idea? Intel has released [20 processors](https://ark.intel.com/Search/FeatureFilter?productType=processors&HyperThreading=false) _this year_ that don't have that. And that's just Intel.

Comment: @marcelm, I didn't know that.

Comment: There are also use cases where best performance requires that hyperthreading be turned off in the BIOS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under given conditions:

> terminal command which doesn't require the executing user to be in the sudoers group and also to be universal and not requiring to install additional packages.

the obvious simplest method for unmodified VMs, which owners intentionally haven't tried to hide fact the OS is VM, is

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
```

More possibilities:

- [How to detect virtualization](https://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/)
- [16 Methods To Check If A Linux System Is Physical or Virtual Machine](https://www.2daygeek.com/check-linux-system-physical-virtual-machine-virtualization-technology/)

Outside of the given by OP author conditions there are more complicated approaches like this one: [Where am I? Operating System and Virtualization Identification Without System Calls](http://www.thought.net/papers/wright-whereami-paper.pdf)

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov You're welcome!

Comment: Without additional configuration, a libvirt-kvm-VM shows as "Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)" when running ``cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name``, so I’m not sure how useful that is.

Comment: @JonasWielicki That's a well defined system description used by default for any QEMU-based VM though, and is never seen on normal hardware.

Comment: @JonasWielicki `Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)` is well known fingerprint of QEMU/KVM virtual machines. By the way, this fingerprint can be easily overriden: https://askubuntu.com/questions/564643/how-to-change-qemu-default-machine

Comment: @JonasWielicki, `pr -t  /sys/class/dmi/id/sys_vendor /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name` the content of these two files should also give you pretty accurate idea whether the system is physical or virtual.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Ha, I didn’t know that. It seemed very realistic to me somehow.

Comment: @JonasWielicki On a real system, it's usually either a platform name (for example my laptop is a System76 Oryx Pro, and it gives `Oryx Pro`), or a product name for the baseboard (for example, my DIY home server system gives `MS-7A33`, which is the model of the motherboard).

Answer (score 13):

This also requires systemd (which is pretty ubiquitous these days anyways), but [`systemd-detect-virt`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html) is a better tool to tell whether this is running on physical or virtual hardware.

You can take a look at the [logic](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v239/src/basic/virt.c#L307) used by `systemd-detect-virt`, you'll notice that it actually looks at many places to detect several distinct virtualization technologies...

I think something naïve such as looking at `lscpu` output might work in some cases some of the time, but I think it would hardly work all the time. Also please note that many technologies make it possible (and even likely) for VMs to have more than one thread per core, so I don't even think that particular feature is sufficient to do any kind of reliable detection here.

Comment: I am thinking that if the minimum and maximum frequency are missing from the lscpu then this could also be an indication that the machine is indeed VM. But your method seems to be more reliable.

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov That could also mean that frequency scaling is completely disabled for some other reason though, so it's not reliable.